# How to provide custom template declared inside my theme .theme file as variable inside page twig template

Tags: theming, 8

In my theme, I implemented HOOK_theme to declare custom twig template.
How can I provide/preprocess this template as variable ready to to output inside my page.twig.html template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presume you have something like:

```
HOOK_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    // mycustomtheme.html.twig
    'mycustomtheme' => [
      'variables' => [
        'var1' => NULL,
        'var2' => NULL,
        'var3' => NULL,
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

You can preprocess the `page.html.twig` theme and add your theme output as a variable:

```
function HOOK_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $var1 = 'foo';
  $var2 = 'bar';
  $var3 = 'baz';
  $variables['content']['customcontent'] = [
    '#theme' => 'mycustomtheme',
    '#var1' => $var1,
    '#var2' => $var2,
    '#var3' => $var3,
  ];
}
```

And then you should be able to print it on `page.html.twig`:

```
{{ content.customcontent }}
```

Comment: Thanks @Beebee, I found this way I can also place my custom theme directly in $variables top level as $variables['mycustomtheme']. But your example helped me to fully understand the potential flexibility of the implementation.